Excel - Custom Format - Displaying concatenated values from two other cells
I have values in 3 cells (Actually 1 Column (B) and two cells)
B1, A2, A3
How do I create a custom format for column B that
displays the value entered into B1 and the Existing value in A2 and the existing value in A3?
EG
B1 has a value entered of 12
A2 has an existing value of Super
A3 has an existing value of 1234
I would like B1 to display 12 Super 1234
The reason I would like to use a custom format for Column B is that I will be using many rows in Column B and simply want to enter the number or text value for the cells in column B
The values of A2 and A3 do change from time to time and this should be automatically reflected in the custom format for column B
Hope there is a simple way to do this

This cannot be done directly, because there can be no reference to the cell content in the format code. You can work around this by using an event procedure Worksheet_Change that changes the format code in column B if the contents of cells A2 or A3 change.
Place the code in the sheet module.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A3")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim f As Variant
    f = Array(Chr(34), Range("A2").Value, Range("A3").Value, Chr(34))
    Columns("B").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    Columns("B").NumberFormat = "General" & Join(f) & _
             ";@" & Join(f)
End Sub

I assume that both numbers or texts will be entered into the cells in column B. If only numbers, then the last line of code can be shortened to:
Columns("B").NumberFormat = "General" & Join(f)



Thank you MGonet for helping me with this.  The code works well and was easy to implement.
